# When can work send you home without pay?

Tags: salary, company-policy

I'm doing some work in the film industry as an extra actor. Usually we are described the scene and told to bring clothes that would fit the setting. For example they would tell us "bring light colored clothes you would wear for a hike on a warm day". They have wardrobe stylists who's job it is to make sure the clothing is right and help out as needed. Also, the wardrobe stylist bring their own clothes to lend if minor changes are needed, but sometimes they run out of supplies.

The other day they told me the clothes I had brought weren't "fancy" enough and I may be sent home. They told me to wait around and see as they may get more loaner clothes. I contacted my agent to ask how pay would work if I was sent home. They replied with a rather vague message basically saying:

> as long as you brought a few changes of clothes that were a reasonable
>   reflection of what was asked, then the stylists would lend you any you
>   need and assist. However if you showed up with junk and got sent home
>   then you don't get paid.

My problem was the waiting around to see part. It wouldn't be fair if I stood around for 3+ hours and then sent home without pay. Are there any laws regarding this? How long would it be advisable to wait until leaving? I arrived on time at 8, and was informed my clothes weren't fancy enough by 10 and told to wait around. It was another couple hours until I actually got clothes so I could have potentially wasted a lot of time.

Just to be clear I think it's fair to be sent home without pay if they show up without the right tools, but I don't think it's fair to be told to stand around for hours knowing you may go home without pay.

Also I offered to go home and pickup more appropriate clothing and they said no.

Comment: We can't tell you the value of your time, the value of the experience and exposure,, etc.... so we can't tell you how long to wait. It does sound like it would be very valuable to learn how to read the casting/costuming specs more accurately, though.

Comment: Btw, they aren't sending you home without pay. You weren't hired.

Comment: Your agent is going to know much more about this than random strangers on the internet.

Comment: @keshlam it's a bit different if you signed in and had already been there for several hours

Comment: Honestly I don't see why this is a bad question?

Comment: Signing in just means you have a place in the queue, not that you've been hired. If you're going to deal with being an extra, you're going to have to accept that this is how the business works -- you're there on spec, and sometimes it isn't going to work. You _could_ have conceded when they said your garb didn't cut it; you chose to wait and hope. Hope didn't pan out this time. But it was your decision, and you aren't hired until they tell you that you're hired... Just as we remind folks applying for other jobs that an offer without a contract is not an offer.

Answer (score 7):

1. You're not an employee of the production company.  You're an extra coming in through an agency.  There is no employer-employee relationship between you and the production company.
2. As far as your time is concerned and whether you get paid for it under perfect conditions or any less-than-perfect conditions, that's totally dependent on what the contract (you signed one, right?) between you and your agent.
3. You're *probably* not an employee of your agent.  If you didn't fill out a W-4 and I-9, you're not an employee, so you don't have the same protections (under state laws) as would others.